Status bar on ios is not visible on stack screen of Expo router
hello guys I have auth screen and tab screen with protected routes. Tab screen status bar working fine where as in auth stack screen I am unable to see status bar. below is the code of auth stack screen.
import { View, Text,  } from 'react-native'
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { Stack, useNavigation, useRouter } from 'expo-router'
import useAuthStore from '@/src/store/AuthStore'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'


const _layout = () => {

  return (
    <>
    <StatusBar style='auto' />
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name='index'
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name='register'
        options={{
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerTitle: '',
        }}

      />
    </Stack>
    </>


  )
}

export default _layout

In this image status bar is visible

but here in the login stack screen status bar is not visible

here is the code of Tab Screen layout page.
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Stack, Tabs, useRouter, useSegments } from 'expo-router'
import CustomHeader from '@/src/components/CustomHeader'
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Foundation } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { scale, verticalScale, moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { constant } from '@/src/constant/constant';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';


const _layout = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const segments = useSegments()
  const hide  = segments.includes("settings" ) 

  Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
    handleNotification: async () => ({
      shouldShowAlert: true,
      shouldPlaySound: false,
      shouldSetBadge: false,
    }),
  });


  return (
    <>
    
    <Tabs
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarStyle:{
        backgroundColor:'white', 
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 4,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.30,
        shadowRadius: 4.65,

        elevation: 8,
        display: hide ? "none" : "flex",

        
      },
      tabBarLabel:'', 
     
      
      
      
    }}
    
    >
      <Tabs.Screen name='index'
        options={{
          headerShown:false,
          tabBarIcon:({focused})=><MaterialIcons name="space-dashboard" size={30} color={focused? constant.fontColor:'lightgray'} />, 
          
         
          
        }}
      />
        <Tabs.Screen name='transaction'
        options={{
          tabBarIcon:({focused})=>  <Foundation name="graph-bar" size={30} color={focused? constant.fontColor:'lightgray'}/>,  
          // headerTransparent:true,
          headerTitle:()=><Text style={{fontSize:scale(18), fontWeight:'bold'}}>Transactions</Text>, 
          headerLeft :()=>(<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>router.back()} style={{}}><Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={24} color="black" /></TouchableOpacity>), 
          headerLeftContainerStyle:{paddingLeft:20},
          headerShown:false
          
          
        }}
      />
       <Tabs.Screen name='settings'
        options={{
          headerTitle:()=><Text style={{fontSize:scale(18), fontWeight:'bold'}}>Settings</Text>, 
          headerLeft :()=>(<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>router.back()} style={{}}><Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={24} color="black" /></TouchableOpacity>), 
          headerLeftContainerStyle:{paddingLeft:20},
          headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#fcf4f8'},
          headerShadowVisible:false,
          
          
          
          href:null
        }}
      />

      
    </Tabs>
    </>
  )
}

export default _layout

